# How can I get the correct text definition of a generic type using reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am working on code generation and ran into a snag with generics. Here is a "simplified" version of what is causing me issues.

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
string text = dictionary.GetType().FullName;
```

With the above code snippet the value of `text` is as follows:

```
 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.DateTime, mscorlib, 
 Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

(Line breaks added for better readability.)

Is there a way to get the type name (`type`) in a different format without parsing the above string? I desire the following result for `text`:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String, System.DateTime>
```

Comment: Note that if you remove `.FullName` and use `.ToString()` instead, you get the "text" ``System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.DateTime]`` which is more readable, and close to what you want.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no built-in way to get this representation in the .Net Framework.  Namely because there is no way to get it correct.  There are a good number of constructs that are not representable in C# style syntax.  For instance "<>foo" is a valid type name in IL but cannot be represented in C#.

However, if you're looking for a pretty good solution it can be hand implemented fairly quickly.  The below solution will work for most situations.  It will not handle

1. Nested Types
2. Illegal C# Names
3. Couple of other scenarios

Example:

```
public static string GetFriendlyTypeName(Type type) {
    if (type.IsGenericParameter)
    {
        return type.Name;
    }

    if (!type.IsGenericType)
    {
        return type.FullName;
    }

    var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    var name = type.Name;
    var index = name.IndexOf("`");
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}.{1}", type.Namespace, name.Substring(0, index));
    builder.Append('<');
    var first = true;
    foreach (var arg in type.GetGenericArguments())
    {
        if (!first)
        {
            builder.Append(',');
        }
        builder.Append(GetFriendlyTypeName(arg));
        first = false;
    }
    builder.Append('>');
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: if you get a chance edit your answer and include "static string GetFriendlyTypeName(Type type) { if (type.IsGenericParameter) { return type.Name; }" in the code block :)

Comment: @Jamey, done.  This is actually pretty weird.  The code block would not add the first line until I added a non-code line between the ordered list and the start of the block.

Comment: and add on top:            bool bArray = false;
            if (type.IsArray) {
                bArray = true;
                type = type.GetElementType();
            }
and on bottom 
            if (bArray) builder.Append("[]");
            return builder.ToString();

to support arrays.

Comment: You might want to handle Nullables, and you might want to add a space after the comma.

Comment: the first block 

" if (type.IsGenericParameter) {...} "


may not be a good idea, since the generic type parameter may be a generic type itself.

Comment: Stuff like `GetFriendlyTypeName(new List<int>().GetEnumerator().GetType())` or `GetFriendlyTypeName(typeof(List<>.Enumerator))` leads to an exception. These are types that are nested inside generic outer types.

Answer (score 23):

A good and clean alternative, thanks to [@LukeH's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584263/whats-the-meaning-of-apostrophe-number-in-the-object-type-of-properties-with/6584285#6584285), is

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
//...
private string GetFriendlyTypeName(Type type)
{
    using (var p = new CSharpCodeProvider())
    {
        var r = new CodeTypeReference(type);
        return p.GetTypeOutput(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: much better then marked as answer(subclasses of generic classes are shown correctly)

Answer (score 4):

This evening I was toying a bit with extension methods and I tried to find an answer for your question. Here is the result: it's a no-warranty code. ;-)

```
internal static class TypeHelper
{
    private const char genericSpecialChar = '`';
    private const string genericSeparator = ", ";

    public static string GetCleanName(this Type t)
    {
        string name = t.Name;
        if (t.IsGenericType)
        {
            name = name.Remove(name.IndexOf(genericSpecialChar));
        }
        return name;
    }

    public static string GetCodeDefinition(this Type t)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}.{1}", t.Namespace, t.GetCleanName());
        if (t.IsGenericType)
        {
            var names = from ga in t.GetGenericArguments()
                        select GetCodeDefinition(ga);
            sb.Append("<");
            sb.Append(string.Join(genericSeparator, names.ToArray()));
            sb.Append(">");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object[] testCases = { 
                                new Dictionary<string, DateTime>(),
                                new List<int>(),
                                new List<List<int>>(),
                                0
                            };
        Type t = testCases[0].GetType();
        string text = t.GetCodeDefinition();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string text = dictionary.ToString();
```

provides almost what you are asking for:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.DateTime]
```

Comment: This is not a generic solution though.  Any type which uses .ToString() will break this solution

Comment: @JaredPar That is solved by using `dictionary.GetType().ToString()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think .NET has anything built-in that would do this, so you will have to do it yourself. I think that the reflection classes provide quite enough information to reconstruct the type name in this form.

Comment: I have tried this path can you elaborate on the solution? I have found not properties or collections that give me this information I can use to reconstruct the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can pass

> System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

into `Type.Parse()`. That is a fully qualified type name, I think.

Comment: Not needed. The original Dictionary.GetType() already contains a collection of type parameters which you can access directly. No need for parsing to get the same result.