# T4 text template with IList

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4, dto

I am using a [T4 template](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/03/11/code-generation-with-t4-an-entities-to-dto-example.aspx) to create DTO's for each of my Data Entities, however it is falling over on using IList.

http://pastebin.com/QxtsDJdt

```
Func<PropertyInfo, bool> scalarProperties = p => !p.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t == typeof(System.Collections.IList) || t == typeof(System.Collections.ICollection));
Func<PropertyInfo, bool> collectionProperties = p => !scalarProperties.Invoke(p);
```

and

```
private bool ExportProperty(PropertyInfo p)
{
    return true;
}
```

I think the section it is falling over on is this, even though IList is an ICollection, the following is not being evaluated to `true`:

```
if (ExportProperty(property) && collectionProperties(property))
```

I am not sure how to debug .tt (T4) files in VS 2010.

The class being generated when a property is an IList is:

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[Namespace.Inspection, Entities, Version=1.0.4168.906, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] Inspections
{
    get; set;
}
```

When it should be:

```
    public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Namespace.Inspection> Inspections
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The link to PastBin is broken, but what I understand from the question; the problem is similar to the following question "[How can I get the correct text definition of a generic type using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401681/how-can-i-get-the-correct-text-definition-of-a-generic-type-using-reflection)". But if you are using Entity Framework, then you can maybe better use POCO or self tracking entities generated from the model, instead of making a translation towards DTOs.

For debugging T4 I just start with coding my logic in a separate class, which I move to the T4 file or call from it. I also installed the free [T4 toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) extension, and at first sight it is helpful, but I just started learning/using code generation. So maybe better solutions or practices exist.