# What's the meaning of "apostrophe + number" in the object type of properties with generics (eg. "Collection`1")?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, fully-qualified-naming

I have an object (`MyObject`) with a property (`MyProperty`). I want to get it's type name (i.e. `String` or `MyClass` etc.). I use:

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(MyObject).GetProperty("MyProperty");
Console.WriteLine(propInfo.PropertyType.Name);
Console.WriteLine(propInfo.PropertyType.FullName);
```

No problem with simple types, but when `MyProperty` is a generic type, I face problems on getting it's name (e.g. `Collection<String>`). It prints:

> Collection`1
>
> System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

**What is that `` `1 ``? And how can I obtain "`Collection<String>`"?**

Comment: Collection`1 means a generic collection with 1 generic type parameter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `` `1 `` means a generic type, with 1 generic parameter.

One way of getting the string is by using the [System.CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx), as suggested by [@LukeH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55847/lukeh):

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var p = new CSharpCodeProvider())
            {
                var r = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(Dictionary<string, int>));
                
                Console.WriteLine(p.GetTypeOutput(r));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401681/how-can-i-get-the-correct-text-definition-of-a-generic-type-using-reflection).
See below for @[jaredpar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar)'s code:

```
public static string GetFriendlyTypeName(Type type) {
    if (type.IsGenericParameter)
    {
        return type.Name;
    }

    if (!type.IsGenericType)
    {
        return type.FullName;
    }

    var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    var name = type.Name;
    var index = name.IndexOf("`");
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}.{1}", type.Namespace, name.Substring(0, index));
    builder.Append('<');
    var first = true;
    foreach (var arg in type.GetGenericArguments())
    {
        if (!first)
        {
            builder.Append(',');
        }
        builder.Append(GetFriendlyTypeName(arg));
        first = false;
    }
    builder.Append('>');
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You might want to handle Nullables, and you might want to add a space after the comma.

Comment: If you copy the complete source, you might want to credit JaredPar with more than just a link to the question...

Comment: `type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName`

Comment: @SLaks, that gives the same (with `1).

Answer (score 8):

This is a CLR internal typename.

The number is the number of generic type parameters, since types can be overloaded.
 (`` Func`1 `` and `` Func`2 `` are different types)

There is no built-in way to get a C#-style typename, since the CLR has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: You can actually get at the C#-style name using CodeDom, but I probably wouldn't bother! Something like `using (var p = new CSharpCodeProvider()) { var r = new CodeTypeReference(propInfo.PropertyType); Console.WriteLine(p.GetTypeOutput(r)); }`

Comment: @LukeH: Looking at the source, that only handles arrays, not generics.

Comment: @LukeH, i think that comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

SLaks already explained what `1 means.

About your second question: You can obtain the name of the generic type parameters by using [Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx):

```
if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType) {
    Type[] typeArguments = propInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
    // typeArguments now contains an array of types ({String} in your example).
}
```

Comment: He wants a string, not an array of type parameters.

Comment: @SLaks: Good point. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. ;-)