# How do I get a string representation from a nullable type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

Say I have something like

```
var T = Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]");
```

which is a nullable datetime.

`T.FullName` gives me:

```
"System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
```

How can I extract `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` as a string representation from the Type?

Comment: see question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401681/how-can-i-get-the-correct-text-definition-of-a-generic-type-using-reflection; (this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6592598/1506454)

Comment: I missed it, should I delete the question?

Comment: I wrote a method for exactly this purpose 2 years ago (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/621812/User-friendly-names-for-Types) but I really like the solution in the answer ASh pointed out! (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6592598/1506454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in this way:

```
var T = Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]");
Type nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(T);
string typeName = nullableType != null ? nullableType.Name + "?" : T.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Type.FullName` returns the full assembly qualified name for the generic arguments. But the `ToString()` method will print a much more friendly name, maybe this is what you want:

```
System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]
```

Please note that if the generic arguments are not from the `mscorlib` library, the type name returned by `ToString` might not be able to be parsed by `Type.GetType(string)` method.